# Trying to issue a PHP recommendation off of HTML form input

Tags: php, html

It's not just a regular input it's a selection the user can pick one, none or all of them and depending on that data different recommendations will be issued. For the sake of this, I've kept it simple. When I execute this function it just defaults to "You can do more to market your dealership." regardless of what I select on the HTML form. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

```
function adMix () {
$tv = $_POST['tv'];
$radio = $_POST['radio'];
$search = $_POST['search'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
if (isset($tv) || ($radio) || ($search) || ($mobile) || ($mail)) {
    echo "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign.";
} else {
    echo "You can do more to market your dealership.";
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML as requested.

```
 <form action="calc.php" method="post">
 <p># of New Cars Sold in Last Year:</p>
 <input type="text" name="newsold">
 <p># of Used Cars Sold in Last Year:</p>
 <input type="text" name="usedsold">
 <p>Marketing Mix:</p>    
 <input type="checkbox" name="TV" value="TV">TV<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Radio" value="Radio">Radio<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Search" value="Search">Search<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Mobile" value="Mobile">Mobile<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Mail" value="Mail">Direct Mail<br>
 <br>
 <input type=submit value=submit>
 </form>
```

Comment: Do you use checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care the values of the variables I will try something like this:

```
<?php
function adMix() {
    $tv = isset($_POST['tv']);
    $radio = isset($_POST['radio']);
    $search = isset($_POST['search']);
    $mobile = isset($_POST['mobile']);
    $mail = isset($_POST['mail']);
    if ($tv || $radio || $search || $mobile || $mail) {
        echo "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign.";
    } else {
        echo "You can do more to market your dealership.";
    }
}
```

if you care about the value of the variables I will recommend you to do like this:

```
<?php
function adMix() {
    $tv = isset($_POST['tv'])  ? $_POST['tv']: false;
    $radio = isset($_POST['radio']) ? $_POST['radio']: false;
    $search = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search']: false;
    $mobile = isset($_POST['mobile']) ? $_POST['mobile']: false;
    $mail = isset($_POST['mail']) ? $_POST['mail']: false;
    if ($tv || $radio || $search || $mobile || $mail) {
        echo "You are running a comprehensive ad campaign.";
        //Do something with th variables
    } else {
        echo "You can do more to market your dealership.";
    }
}
```

And if you care if the value is `empty` I will change `isset` to `!empty` which also will check if `isset` and then it will check if is `0`, `null`,"", `false` or `array()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in your code. In its current state, the first statement will only be executed if `$tv` is set, or if the value of one of the other variables evaluates to `true`.

If you are trying to determine whether each variable is set, wrap each check in an `isset()`:

```
if (isset($tv) || isset($radio) || isset($search) || isset($mobile) || isset($mail)) {
```

This approach will be problematic for two reasons: You will get notices when trying to access non-existent array indexes in `$_POST`, and may experience unexpected results when trying do something logical with `isset()` called on variables that you just explicitly set.

For better results, consider checking the $_POST elements themselves to determine if they are set, rather than checking to see whether the variables you just set are set:

```
if (isset($_POST['tv']) || isset($_POST['radio']...)
```

Comment: I tried that which I think would work for text inputs but its a series of checkboxes. I used your code and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Consider showing your HTML as well; if the code above does not detect that the requested value is set in the post, there may be a reason in the form itself.